# UnityでWebGL形式で出力してもindex.htmlに明記しているファイルが生成されない

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

はじめまして。
Unityでtestという名前のプロジェクトを作って、WebGLを選択→buildしたところ、作られたindex.htmlファイルには以下の内容のファイルを読み込むように書いてありました。

```
  var buildUrl = "Build";
  var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/test.loader.js";
  var config = {
    dataUrl: buildUrl + "/test.data.gz",
    frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/test.framework.js.gz",
    codeUrl: buildUrl + "/test.wasm.gz",
    streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
    companyName: "DefaultCompany",
    productName: "KIMLAND",
    productVersion: "0.1",
    showBanner: unityShowBanner,
  };
```

ですが、実際生成されたファイルは以下のようになります。
Build/
├test.data.gz
├test.loader.js
TemplateData/
├ 各種画像ファイル
index.html

index.htmlを立ち上げても、test.framework.js.gz　のファイルがないためエラーがでます。
開発buildのチェックは外して、buildしています。

https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2021.1/Manual/webgl-building.html
こちらを読んでも、なぜファイルができないのかピンときません。

どうやったらtest.framework.js.gzのファイルは生成されるんでしょうか？
unity初心者の相談で申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。